# LibVLC Demux Cannot Peek

Tags: c++, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc

I'm attempting to use LibVLC to eventually stream video in a larger application, but for now I'm working off of a [tutorial](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/). Current goal is simply to stream a video saved on my computer

When I walk through the program with the debugger, the error code

> [00000216266e7650] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek

appears after line 56:

> libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);

The video had to be placed in the same location as main.cpp (instead of wherever I wanted with an explicit file path). It's a .wmv file.

I am using LibVLC 3.0.7.1, obtained as a NuGet package for Visual Studio. 
I cannot build libVLC from the source because I a) struggle to use Linux and don't have easy access to it, b) cannot install all of the tools needed to crosscompile on a Windows machine, and c) because I am still very new to this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

//extern "C" {
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\vlc.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_media_player.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_dialog.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_events.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_media.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_media_discoverer.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_media_library.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_media_list.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_media_list_player.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_renderer_discoverer.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_version.h>
#include <C:\GIT\PVI\packages\VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows.3.0.7.1\build\x64\include\vlc\libvlc_vlm.h>
//}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    libvlc_instance_t * inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

    /* Load the VLC engine */
    inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);

    /* Create a new item */
    m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, "1_Holiday_Sale_v6.wmv");
    //m = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, "/path/to/test.mov");

    /* Create a media player playing environement */
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);

    /* No need to keep the media now */
    libvlc_media_release(m);

#if 0
    /* This is a non working code that show how to hooks into a window,
     * if we have a window around */
    libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow(mp, xid);
    /* or on windows */
    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(mp, hwnd);
    /* or on mac os */
    libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject(mp, view);
#endif

    /* play the media_player */
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);

    Sleep(10); /* Let it play a bit */

    /* Stop playing */
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);

    /* Free the media_player */
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);

    libvlc_release(inst);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer instead of deleting just in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Sleep() function takes in the time parameter in milliseconds. Boost that up appropriately and it works fine.